# Tab sliding - how to?

Tags: java, android

The problem is with tab activity. when i'm run this app with  is worked fine.but when i slide or tap the tab it's totally shut down.please anyone help me out.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;


    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    }





    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    tab1 tab1 = new tab1();
                    return tab1;

                case 1:
                    tab2 tab2 = new tab2();
                    return tab2;
                case 3:
                    tab3 tab3 =new tab3();
                    return tab3;

                default: return null ;
            }



        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Protisthan";
                case 1:`enter code here`
                    return "Eknojore";
                case 2:
                    return "Onnorokom";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

and here is logcat file . app run smoothly but when i try to chage the tab then it's get cushed.

```
11-14 12:08:12.460 30777-30777/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
11-14 12:08:12.535 30777-30777/? I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
11-14 12:08:12.729 30777-30783/com.example.mn.tabt I/art: Debugger is active
11-14 12:08:12.736 30777-30777/com.example.mn.tabt I/System.out: Debugger has connected
11-14 12:08:12.736 30777-30777/com.example.mn.tabt I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
11-14 12:08:12.936 30777-30777/com.example.mn.tabt I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
11-14 12:08:13.136 30777-30777/com.example.mn.tabt I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
11-14 12:08:13.336 30777-30777/com.example.mn.tabt I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
11-14 12:08:13.537 30777-30777/com.example.mn.tabt I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
11-14 12:08:13.737 30777-30777/com.example.mn.tabt I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
11-14 12:08:13.938 30777-30777/com.example.mn.tabt I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
11-14 12:08:14.138 30777-30777/com.example.mn.tabt I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
11-14 12:08:14.339 30777-30777/com.example.mn.tabt I/System.out: debugger has settled (1406)
11-14 12:08:14.356 30777-30777/com.example.mn.tabt W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.mn.tabt-1/lib/arm64
11-14 12:08:14.399 30777-30777/com.example.mn.tabt W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
11-14 12:08:14.544 30777-30777/com.example.mn.tabt I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
11-14 12:08:14.557 30777-30777/com.example.mn.tabt E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
11-14 12:08:14.649 30777-30849/com.example.mn.tabt E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
11-14 12:08:14.649 30777-30849/com.example.mn.tabt I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-14 12:08:14.655 30777-30849/com.example.mn.tabt W/OpenGLRenderer: load: so=/system/lib64/libhwuibp.so
                                                                     dlopen failed: library "/system/lib64/libhwuibp.so" not found
11-14 12:08:14.655 30777-30849/com.example.mn.tabt W/OpenGLRenderer: Initialize Binary Program Cache: Load Failed
11-14 12:08:14.655 30777-30849/com.example.mn.tabt E/HAL: load: id=gralloc != hmi->id=gralloc
11-14 12:08:21.698 30777-30777/com.example.mn.tabt I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 30777 SIG: 9
```

`

here the tab1 class. similarly i create two more class.for 3 fragment.
 `

```
    public class tab1 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

if anyone want to see the xml file of main class . here it is .

`

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

`

Comment: add `android:largeHeap="true"` in application section

Comment: please describe lil bit briefly sir. did you mean the xml section?

Comment: Add this in your manifest section.

Comment: `<application android:largeHeap="true"`

Comment: got it sir. let me check

Comment: no sir it's not working.

Comment: Disable Instant Run

Comment: i have already disable instant run but still now it's not working

Comment: `default: return tab1;` or remove `default: return null ;`

Comment: i found a solution someone gave me in that comment section . it's in case section. i wrote 3 instead of 2. silly mistake. sorry and thank you sir. :)

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya your ans was correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                tab1 tab1 = new tab1();
                return tab1;

            case 1:
                tab2 tab2 = new tab2();
                return tab2;
            case 3: // Should be 2
                tab3 tab3 =new tab3();
                return tab3;

            default: return null ;
        }
```

At first, rectify your **`CASE`** section.

```
 case 2: 
            tab3 tab3 =new tab3();
            return tab3;
```

- **Disable Instant Run** .

Comment: it's actually case 2 in there sir. still got crushed when i try to slide tab.

Answer (score 0):

There is an another solution for this problem

```
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    setupViewPager(mViewPager); //Replace your line to this

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

//method for adding fragment to the adapter

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    SectionsPagerAdapter adapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new TabOne(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFragment(new TabSecond(), "TWO");
    adapter.addFragment(new TabThird(), "THREE");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}


public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    // add this method in your adapter
    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You should explain how it is different to the other one.

Comment: There is no difference to other one. it is another way to solve this problem if problem exist and also it is way for creating dynamic fragment if you have no. of objects for showing same UI with different data then you can use this code with doing minor changes like              private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager, ArrayList<Object> objectList) {
    SectionsPagerAdapter adapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
 if(Object object: objectList){
  adapter.addFragment(new TabFragment(), object.getTitle);
 }
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

Comment: private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager, ArrayList<Object> objectList) {
    SectionsPagerAdapter adapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
 for(Object object: objectList){
  adapter.addFragment(new TabFragment(), object.getTitle);
 }
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}